# How to detect unexpected socket client disconnection java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I am creating simple socket Server/Client app in Java. I have successfully connected the clients and to the server.

How can we detect if the socket is disconnected such as

- If the user forcibly close the client app
- The client computer turned off
- Other unexpected event happening on client app that will cause it to terminate

Comment: you can write a service which checks the connection after some time. By sending a request.

Comment: So if the client is disconnected. I think it will only give an exception? What exception should I determine in order to  specify that the client is really disconnected?

Comment: once you send a request and didn't get any response you can assume it's disconnected although there are lot of factors that also need to be consider. If it's disconnected you response will be null

Comment: Ok I think I have an idea. Let me try it out. Thanks man..